# What machine learning method can i use to predict the next image in a sequence?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I have a sequence of images below.

[image]

It takes a straight line, breaks it in half, and then morphs them into an angle image.

After the training is complete, I should be able to give it only one start image of any length, and it should give me the angle image as output.

What machine learning method can i use (given the training sequence) to predict the final output image?

**[Edit]** - I am not trying to classify an image. I am trying to make the AI generate an output image given a source image.

Comment: Your should design a Reinforcement Learning Model and an appropriate corresponding rewarding function - this is the only way I see this is working in my perspective though!.

Comment: Why is this question being closed? Is it not a valid question? How else can i ask for direction? ai/machine learning methods have is a vast field with many terms/methods/approaches. I do not even know what the terms are I should use to google it properly. Every google search only shows image classification methods. I ask the question here and now it has to votes to close it? I am not looking for libraries or software. I just want to know what ML method can solve something like this.

Comment: I did not vote for closing this one. However, I think the voters' point is such a question should be asked on ai.stackexchange.com because here is mostly about the implementation problems (i.e. OP has developed some code but facing some kind of problem).

Comment: Maybe you can use auto encoders. One way to do so can be to make use of 2 auto encoders. The first one should generate the split lines (second image) from the input. The second encoder should generate the angle image from the split. So `encoder_1` learns length and half split and `encoder_2` learns length and angle part.

Comment: A similar implementation should be possible with GANs as well. As this is a very specific task with not much variation, you will have to generate tons of data to train and at the same time make sure that the model does not overfit.